# Override default cropping in Wordpress

Tags: theme-development, functions, cropping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make add_image_size() crop from the top?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20923/how-can-i-make-add-image-size-crop-from-the-top)

Is there any way to have cropping happen from the center point in an image? All of my Featured Image uploads are cropped poorly (mostly website screenshots), and I'd love to have those crop instead from top/center for preview versions of the image (such as what would show on index.php [loop] in the theme).

[I saw this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917177/change-default-crop-origin-of-a-featured-image-in-wordpress-thumbnail), but I absolutely hate hacking the core out of fear a Wordpress upgrade with cause my changes to vanish. Any recommendations are welcome. I prefer to do this via functions.php if possible, rather than edit my 99% completed theme.

Comment: See also: [User-friendly cropping of post thumbnails?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1733/user-friendly-cropping-of-post-thumbnails) and [Why is the thumbnail crop leaving the wrong portion of the image?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3745/why-is-the-thumbnail-crop-leaving-the-wrong-portion-of-the-image)

Answer (score 1):

Checkout these plugins:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/scissors/screenshots/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easy-image-crop/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-image-cropper/

Comment: These are great plugins (in fact, one of the plugins' functionality is actually built into Wordpress core now), but they have absolutely nothing to do with my question. I'm not trying to figure out cropping for images that go into the body or WYSIWYG area. I am, however, trying to find a way to override the default image cropping behavior when uploading a "featured image" on the right side of the page. I think we can do this in media.php, but I'm trying to find some creative way to accomplish this in functions.php (in my theme folder) so that I don't have Wordpress upgrades undoing my changes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like add_image_size() may be the only way to do it. I was searching for a way to do it site-wide for all images, but I may have to settle for doing it to each image size....custom, in my theme.