# Different thumbnail size than actual picture in post

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails

I am wondering how to achieve something specific.  I am not sure if this functionality is already built into Wordpress, or if there is some PHP happening.

This is the site I am basing some of my design from: http://www.premiumpixels.com/

As you can see, the images that are on the front page are cropped, yet, when you click on the post itself, it gives you a larger view all together.  Attempts to actually crop the image in Wordpress and make it a featured image has been futile.  I am wondering how to achieve this?

It seems like he is using the front page thumbnail as a featured image and the actual blog post image has just been merely inserted.  Yet, when I try this, I get both images on my front page.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite simple to implement, using core `post-thumbnails` functionality.

First, you need to *add Theme support for the feature*, via `functions.php`:

```
<?php
function wpse54920_setup_theme() {
    // Support post thumbnails
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse54920_setup_theme' );
?>
```

Next, you need to *define your custom image sizes*, using [**add_image_size()**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size). Let's say you want the following custom image sizes:

- `archive-index-featured`, 150px x 100px, hard-cropped
- `post-header-featured`, 250px wide, box-resized

Define them as follows (building on our code above):

```
<?php
function wpse54920_setup_theme() {

    // Support post thumbnails
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

    // Add Archive Index Featured image size
    add_image_size( 'archive-index-featured', 150, 100, true );

    // Add Post Header Featured image size
    add_image_size( 'post-header-featured', 250, 9999, false );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse54920_setup_theme' );
?>
```

Now, you simply need to *output the appropriate image size in the appropriate template file*, or via the appropriate conditional. For simplicity, I'll use the latter approach:

```
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    // Determine image size based on context
    $featured_image_size = ( is_single || is_page() ? 'post-header-featured' : 'archive-index-featured' );
    // Output the post featured image
    the_post_thumbnail( $featured_image_size );
}
?>
```

Alternately, you could simply call `the_post_thumbnail( 'post-header-featured' )` in `single.php` and/or `page.php`, and call `the_post_thumbnail( 'archive-index-featured' )` in other template files.

Comment: I understand this functionality, but the cropping function in Wordpress doesn't crop a _portion_ of the bigger image, which is ultimately what I want.  Going through the website example I gave, it seems as though he has a portion cropped as a featured image on the front page and when you click through, he shows the bigger image.  My question is, how did he crop a _portion_ of the bigger image, use it as a thumbnail and then display a bigger image on a click through?  The bigger image on the actual single.php page is not a featured image, it's an inserted one.

Comment: **Hard-crop** crops to exact dimensions, and will crop a *portion* of the image. **Box-resize** will scale the image proportionally, using the smallest specified dimension. Thus, specifying `$crop` to `true` for one image, and `false` for the other image, will cause the two images to be cropped/resized differently.

Comment: If **hard-cropping** does what you said it should do, it sounds like this is what I want to use.  However, when I use `add_image_size( 'archive-index-featured', 150, 100, true );` and pass the `the_post_thumbnail` function the class name, I merely get a resize and not a crop.

Comment: **1)** Did you regenerate your Thumbnails after adding a new image size? **2)** What is your original image size? Do the original dimensions also have a ratio of 1.5:1? If so, the hard crop and box resize will result in the same image.

Comment: 1.  Yes.  2.  I am not sure what you mean by that.  For some reason, it's scaling the image down and not cropping.  penandanchor.com is my blog.  I will leave it like so if you want to poke around.  As you can see, the thumbnail is resizing and not cropping a portion of the image on the main page like I want it to.

Comment: Looking at your site, The `'attachment-archive-index-featured'` image is 420px x 200px, cropped, and the original image is 900px x 700px. So: I don't see the problem?

Comment: Perhaps this is just miscommunication at it's best.  I am trying to still have the image be at full size, but just take a portion out of that full size image.  If you look at premiumpixels, there is no scaling of the image.  All he did was take a chunk out of the full size picture and used it as a featured image.  Perhaps using Photoshop for all of my images is the way to go?

Comment: For instance, look at these two images: http://www.premiumpixels.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/feat4.jpg ... http://www.premiumpixels.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/preview4.jpg  .. The first is the featured image, the second the blog image.  All he did was cut out everything except the middle.  Can this be done?

Comment: What you're looking for is how to customize the **way** that WordPress crops images. [See this question/answer for more information on that.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1733/user-friendly-cropping-of-post-thumbnails)

Comment: At this point, I think I may just use Photoshop, because it still looks to be fairly difficult and not get exactly what you want.  Here's a better question:  How do I crop two images and have the first be displayed on the front page and the second be displayed on a entry?  If I merely insert the second image, it will show up on the front page.

Comment: I would ask that as a separate question. :) (Be sure to search first; that ground may have been covered already.)

Comment: Thanks for all of your help, I am checking this as an answer, because I did find my answer to the question I asked originally.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [Timthumb](http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/), a small php script for cropping, zooming and resizing web images.

On my site I'm using it to do something very similar to what your example (premiumpixels) is doing.

The code on the overview page (page.php):

```
<?php
                                        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full');
                                        if($thumbnail){
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="img_post">
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" class="blogpost_img">
                                        <span class="background_3"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/post_img_arrow.png" alt="Read More" /></span>
                                        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/framework/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $thumbnail[0]; ?>&amp;h=230&amp;w=340" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div><!-- /img_post -->

                                    <?php
                                        }
                                    ?>
```

The code on the detail page (single.php):

```
                                <?php
                                        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full');
                                        if($thumbnail){
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="img_post">

                                        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/framework/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $thumbnail[0]; ?>&amp;h=230&amp;w=680" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>

                                    </div><!-- /img_post -->
```

Comment: -1. There is absolutely no need to use TimThumb here, when core functionality is more than adequate.

Comment: @ChipBennett interesting implementation. Didn't know you could do it that way.