# Basic gallery plugin suggestion

Tags: plugins, customization, themes, gallery

I'm developing a custom wp theme which needs a gallery function. I looked over a few popular gallery plugins, but all of them seem "bloated" with a lot of unnecessary stuff.

Do you have any recommendations of a light gallery plugin that allows the admin to upload photos and group them into galleries?

Comment: If you have already reviewed a lot of existing plugins, it might be useful to share your comments in an answer to your question. This way others can benefit from your work, and append to the list if you make it "Community Wiki". I have done [a similar thing](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1463/resizing-images-to-the-actual-size-used-in-the-editor/3877#3877) when researching image resizers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with the built-in gallery functionality? Seems to match your description pretty well. ;-)

Comment: the problem is that these galleries are attached to normal posts

Comment: Or to pages, or to other custom post types, no? You can always use my auto-thickbox plugin, if you need something a tiny bit fancier than the default WP gallery.