# Content area is too small

Tags: post-content

I want to change to the new twenty fourteen theme because it's a nice look and feel.
However if I try so the content is reduced only on a small area and a lot of space on the page is unused.

I already tried this:
[how to create a conditional content_width for a wordpress theme?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6499/how-to-create-a-conditional-content-width-for-a-wordpress-theme)
but it does not help me at all.

to give you an image of what i mean look at this:
[Unused pagearea marked in yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sW6ro.png)

Some of you know where and what do I have to change to fit the whole area?

My blog: [www.sysstem.at](http://www.sysstem.at)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit your theme's CSS to do this.

In style.css in your 2014 folder on line 1021:

```
.site-content .entry-header,
.site-content .entry-content,
.site-content .entry-summary,
.site-content .entry-meta,
.page-content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 474px;
}
```

change 474px to whatever you want your content width to go up to. Or set it to 100% to stay full width.