# Media Upload Folder - how to manage

Tags: images, media, uploads

**Situation :**

When uploading an image via the media uploader, WP automatically makes at least 3 additional sizes, that comes to 4 images including the original one. Most of the time, the images will be used at most 2 ( 1 thumbnail for the archive page and 1 for within the post itself. )

**Problem :**

Before long, the site will be bloated with unused images, and that's ok until the time to backup site.

Suppose a new WP site is up and there will be 1 post per day with 1 image per post, for a year, we will have 365 times 4 image files sitting in the upload folder ( 1460 files).

Within 3 years, we will have 4,380 image files all together !!!

**Solution :**

So how do you handle this ?

Comment: Heh. I know photographers who shoot that many (10MB+) photos each week. :-)

Comment: That would come to 500MB+/year :)

Answer (score 7):

A simple answer is that you can remove 2 unused sizes by enter 0 for their width or height. For example, you need only the small thumbnail 150x150 and full-sized image, so enter 0 for width and height of Medium and Large sizez.

Comment: That's a nice trick! [`image_make_intermediate_size()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.4/wp-includes/media.php#L482) indeed skips a size if both the width and the height are zero.

Answer (score 5):

Another chance to recommend [two plugins I created](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1463/resizing-images-to-the-actual-size-used-in-the-editor/4012#4012) that together will do what you want. **Virtual intermediate images** will intercept the creation of the intermediate image sizes: they will not be created on disk, but still exist in the metadata array. This makes WordPress think they exist so you can use them like normal images. The companion plugin, **On-Demand Resizer** will create missing image sizes when they are requested. The first time the image is requested it is created, all subsequent requests will just be served the newly created image.

Answer (score 4):

Images sizes for the purpose of creating/deleting attachments seem to be retrieved with `get_intermediate_image_sizes()` function, that isn't documented in Codex (only briefly mentioned in [3.0 release notes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_3.0#Development.2C_Themes.2C_Plugins)).

That function passes result (combined set of default and custom image sizes) through `intermediate_image_sizes` filter, so you can likely use that hook to disable unwanted sizes.

See [source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.3/wp-includes/media.php#L573) for details.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will check it out, and will report back to this post ( after I actually try it.)   

Still, I wonder why I've never heard or read about this before, it's as if everybody is busy building up new WP sites and not worry about the overhead when it's time to backup and manage thousands of files a few years later.

Comment: Note that not everyone uses media functionality. I don't myself (writing post with Windows Live Writer that uploads images via FTP). Even without multiple sizes I do have over thousand images by now, no backup issues so far.