# Best Apache Log Analyzer Plugin?

Tags: plugins, statistics

What is the best apache log analyzer plugin for WordPress?

Requirements: should produce all reports as available in flashstats: http://www.maximized.com/products/flashstats2006/

Im looking for things such as:

- files that have the highest impact on bandwidth usage,
- potential leechers,
- bad robots, etc...

(on posting it said 'the question you are asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed...' no idea why, im really looking for a plugin that gives really a load of reports preferably multisite wide reporting so that i can see which sites use the highest resources).

**a little update:**

There are analyzers based on embedded elements in a page, the counters and the counter 2.0: pretty complete list: http://tellertest.com/tellers.php. There are many plugins for each of them (currently clicky is #1 and GA is #5) and even so much blockers: http://www.google.nl/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=block+google+analytics

There are also log file analyzers like e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_analytics_software

I think the first class is more for marketing and the second class more for technical people.

I think personally that the second class is more useful than the first class of analyzing what is happening on a server but maybe i am wrong.

Analyzing data can produce infinite reports depending on imagination.

Therefore I was wondering if there was a WordPress specific weblog-weblog Analyzer which among other has Apache logs / Syslogs / Other OS logs as data input. There are 69 pages when i search for 'statistics' in the WordPress Plugin dir....

If not, maybe it is interesting BI addon to create.

Comment: The automatic subjective filter [includes the word "best"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4371/how-does-the-automatic-subjective-filter-work), but of course this does not automatically mean you are asking a bad question. And I once searched for the words `resize` or `crop` in the plugins dir and [published my results](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1463/resizing-images-to-the-actual-size-used-in-the-editor/3877#3877): it was a huge list, but it took less than an hour to go over all of them.

Comment: @jan-fabry: ok :) another update coming... but this going to take some time.

Comment: always first take the time you think it's worth to formulate your question as that always helps to answer it. The more info you provide, the more info you will get or so. It's a bit short to say, but I think you get what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"best apache log analyzer plugin for WordPress"

This is a joke question, right?

If not, no offense, but you're probably new to the web. And if so, you probably should know that Apache logs actually pick up and log:

- Search Engine bots (not just Google: any bot, and there are many, many, many...)
- Comment spam bots
- Ping spam bots
- Referral spam bots
- Other spam bots
- More spam bots
- Did I mention spam bots yet?
- Oh yeah, there might be a few more I forgot...

Seriously though, the only thing you should be using for analytics is Google Analytics or an equivalent (and expensive) piece of software). Unless, of course, you're the only one who actually sees the latter and are not ashamed to tell your customer that his recently search optimized site now has 10k uniques per month -- in spite of the fact that GA tells you that your actual traffic is around 100 real visitors per month. (Seen in real life, don't laugh.)

Re your secondary question, for bandwidth just use the host's default analyzer (usually webanalyzer or equivalent, which for this purpose is arguably good since it *includes* spam bots).

Comment: but ... GA is really my advanced web counter v2.0. There is a lot of other interesting information in the server logs. But.. yes... that hosts default analyzer is urchin ... im looking for reports as e.g. flashstats 2006 gives.

Comment: but ... this is maybe an interesting topic for a blogpost. haha. Apache's SPAM logs, yes. I like to categorize my spam :) I just wondered if the hosts default analyzer would be handier in the wordpress panel itself e.g. by specifiying info per blog domain.

Comment: Google Analytics is something very different than actual logfiles. You may combine both data sources, but relying on GA alone is not good enough. GA cannot track image requests or greedy feed readers for example.

Comment: @toscho: actually, GA tracks pretty much everything you tell it to. Including images, downloads, form usage, flash/video usage, order form amounts, etc. The problem is that most GA plugins stick to adding the GA script with a few cosmetic tweaks.

Comment: @edelwater: there used to be an Analog plugin back in 2006, but I haven't been following it, so don't know if it still exists or works with the current WP version. What's wrong with using the stats from the host's interface for this kind of stuff?

Comment: @Denis: did I mention that the web currently is more spam-afine than email? If not, well, I did it *gg* - the exception is naturally to static sites, get the message or as we said back then: skate or die.

Comment: @Denis GA cannot track hotlinked images, 400 feed requests per hour etc. It is just an external script which may or may not be loaded by UAs. Real log files are much more useful.

Comment: @toscho: Very valid point when it comes to logging. :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is a good old Analog (analog.cx), not very user-friendly, but high adaptable...

Comment: So... there is no plugin but this would be a good basis to build a plugin on?

Comment: sorry, now I see that it is a "plugin" in question. analog is standalone application.

Comment: welcome sasa.radjcic. now problem, I like your answer ;) and I think your intentions are totally ok.