# Regenerate Thumbnails

Tags: custom-post-types

I am using custom image sizes with add_image_size for custom post types.

For example for books custom post type

```
if($post_type_name == 'book'){
    add_image_size('75x75',75,75, true);
    add_image_size('150x150',150,150, true);
}elseif($post_type_name == 'music'){
   add_image_size('200x200',200,200, true);
   add_image_size('400x400',400,400, true);
}
```

But when I regenerate thumbnails it doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`add_image_size`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) is intended to be defined globally (outside of the context of a post type). This is because when images are generated they are not yet attached to a specific post type.

If you're using a plugin or WP CLI to regenerate the thumbnails, you are *outside* of the context of a post type. Therefore those checks are always going to fail.

You should simply do

```
add_image_size('75x75',75,75, true);
add_image_size('150x150',150,150, true);
add_image_size('200x200',200,200, true);
add_image_size('400x400',400,400, true);
```

In your `functions.php`, class file, plugin, etc.

Comment: Thank you but I have a lot of image sizes for different post types. How can I do it on different way?

Comment: @AbuzerKillibacak In that case you may find this post helpful https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1463/resizing-images-to-the-actual-size-used-in-the-editor/4012#4012

It's not possible to define custom image sizes for custom post types (natively within WordPress) however there are a couple of plugins that can do the job.

Comment: It is too complicated for me. I have basic English. And I saved them in different folder for example /upload/book/ or /upload/music/ . Can I do it? Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm sure the language barrier is an additional challenge. I recommend my original answer. Go ahead and generate all image sizes for all post types. Storage is inexpensive. CPU cycles and RAM are expensive. Go ahead and generate the images for all post types, it'll be fine. Your Custom Post Type templates can simply request the proper images sizes.

Comment: I did like your original  answer. But firstly I added image sizes for my custom post type. Then I go media and I chose my images for that custom post type then I regenerate them. Then I did that for other post types. Thank you.